# Как скрыть alert используя Selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

***Когда браузер перенаправляет меня на страницу телеграма, выскакивает alert. Как я могу его скрыть?***

Как выглядит **alert**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код** который я использую:

```
alert = Alert(driver)
alert.dismiss()
```

или:

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Оба варианта выдают одинаковую **ошибку**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: alert появляется на этом url: https://t.me/kaifustore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скорее всего это не модальное окно, посмотрите по f12.
таким образом на него можно и нужно нажать (click) обычным способом

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys

WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

либо необычным

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
username.sendKeys(searchKey);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
action.perform();
```

для справки  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-the-enter-return-key-in-selenium

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/

Comment: В f12 я его всё же не вижу, но если enter отправить, то действительно закроется

Comment: хммм, интересно.

Comment: можете по ссылке https://t.me/kaifustore в ф12 поискать, но там вроде пусто.

Comment: ну, у меня подобное окно появлялось после установки телеграма, так что еще как вариант удалить программу телеграма, ну как вариант.

Comment: телеграм итак не стоит:)